# SimpleXML and PHP XPath expression not returning correct data

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xpath

The following PHP code:

```
<html>
<?php


$name = Secrezy;
$server = Sunstrider;

 $raidurl='http://eu.wowarmory.com/character-achievements.xml?r='.$server.'&cn='.$name.'&c=168';
 print_r($raidurl); // This is to check if the link is valid. Follow the link printed here and you should find a valid XML page
 echo "<br>"; 
 $xmlraid = simplexml_load_file($raidurl);
 $achievement = array($xmlraid->xpath("/category/achievement[@id='4602']"));  
 print_r($achievement);

?>
</html>
```

Isn't working as I would expect it to. Shouldn't $achievement be populated with this:

```
<achievement categoryId="168" dateCompleted="2010-03-26T00:01:00+01:00" desc="Complete the 10-player raid achievements listed below." icon="inv_helmet_74" id="4602" points="25" reward="Reward: Bloodbathed Frostbrood Vanquisher" title="Glory of the Icecrown Raider (10 player)">
```

Instead, I just get an empty array.

Here is the full URL to the page http://eu.wowarmory.com/character-achievements.xml?r=Sunstrider&cn=Secrezy&c=168

Thanks!

Edit: After changing the xpath to /achievements/category/achievement[@id='4602'] which I completely missed, everything works fine. So thanks for that. However, if I implement this into my original code, it still doesn't work as I would expect. I'm sure I'm doing something terribly wrong, so thanks for the help.

```
<?php
echo "<html>
 <head>
  <title>ARMORY.</title>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html' charset=iso-8859-1>
 </head>
 <body>
 <table width='50%' border='1' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='10'>";
ini_set("user_agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; pl-PL; rv:1.9.0.2) Gecko/20121223 Ubuntu/9.25 (jaunty) Firefox/3.8");

$server = "Sunstrider";
$guild = "Operation+Eskimo";

$url='http://eu.wowarmory.com/guild-info.xml?r='.$server.'&gn='.$guild;
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);



$array = array();



foreach($xml->guildInfo->guild->members->character as $char)
  if(strtolower($char['level']) === '80')
  {
        $array[] = $char['name']."<br />";
  } 

$i = 0;
while($array[$i] != null) 
{
 $name = $array[$i];
 $raidurl='http://eu.wowarmory.com/character-achievements.xml?r='.$server.'&cn='.$name.'&c=168';
 $xmlraid = simplexml_load_file($raidurl);
 var_dump($xmlraid);
 echo "<br><br>";
 $achievement = array($xmlraid->xpath("/achievements/category/achievement[@id='4602']")); 
    $i++; 
}


?>

 </body>
</html>
```

That var_dump of xmlraid only produces this (many many times due to $i):

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (2) { ["@attributes"]=>  array(2) { ["lang"]=>  string(5) "en_us" ["requestUrl"]=>  string(27) "/character-achievements.xml" } ["category"]=>  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) { ["category"]=>  array(12) { [0]=>  object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (0) { } [1]=>  object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (0) { } [2]=>  object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (0) { } [3]=>  object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (0) { } [4]=>  object(SimpleXMLElement)#9 (0) { } [5]=>  object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (0) { } [6]=>  object(SimpleXMLElement)#11 (0) { } [7]=>  object(SimpleXMLElement)#12 (0) { } [8]=>  object(SimpleXMLElement)#13 (0) { } [9]=>  object(SimpleXMLElement)#14 (0) { } [10]=>  object(SimpleXMLElement)#15 (0) { } [11]=>  object(SimpleXMLElement)#16 (0) { } } }
```

I should add that I'm very new to PHP so my code isn't great.

Comment: I get totally other tags then you're looking for (div's with classnames). It there something else we should send to see the XML you are trying to use?

Comment: @Wrikken: Which browser do you use? Could be that the XSL stylesheet is automatically applied. If I see the source in Firefox 3.6 i can see the XML.

Comment: Hmmm, nope (opera), which CAN use XSL. But I'll try FF

Comment: Use IE to view the page, and you'll see XML.  (Well, when you view the source you will.)  I'm not sure about FF, but Chrome either triggers some "your browser sucks" switch or transforms the XML even before "view source" views it.  IE actually works better than Chrome in this instance.

Comment: Hmm, even `wget` gets served the stuff transformed...

Comment: James, I updated my answer with the fix for your follow up question.  Please, makes sure to read the comments.  For future reference, it's generally best to keep the questions as atomic as possible.  In other words, you should create a new question for the new issues.  This does depend on the nature of the issue, as it make take longer to explain the issue in a new question.  Or, you may not even know how to word the new question.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't the xpath be:

```
/achievements/category/achievement[@id='4602']
```

Or:

```
//category/achievement[@id='4602']
```

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Update:

The issue with that code is the fact that you were adding `<br />` to the end of each name in `$array`.  Generally, avoid adding formatting in this way, unless there's a good reason.

Also, note my notes in the comments.  Especially, `urlendcode()`.  I left this for you to do with `$url` as I didn't notice it until after starting this edit and I'm lazy. ;)  Note, that once you pass those query string params through `urlencode()` the `+` in the guild name won't be necessary and it will actually get in the way.

```
ini_set("user_agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; pl-PL; rv:1.9.0.2) Gecko/20121223 Ubuntu/9.25 (jaunty) Firefox/3.8");

$server = "Sunstrider";
$guild = "Operation+Eskimo";

$url='http://eu.wowarmory.com/guild-info.xml?r='.$server.'&gn='.$guild;
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$array = array();

foreach ($xml->guildInfo->guild->members->character as $char)
{
    if (strtolower($char['level']) === '80')
    {
        $array[] = $char['name'];
    }
}

foreach ($array as $i => $name)
{
// note that this if statement and $i in the foreach are only here to limit this to 1 for testing, the full list spews out A LOT of data and takes A LONG time
if ($i) 
{
exit;
}
    // note the urlencode() call, that's important
    $raidurl='http://eu.wowarmory.com/character-achievements.xml?r=' . urlencode($server) . '&cn=' . urlencode($name) . '&c=168';
    $xmlraid = simplexml_load_file($raidurl);

    // note the pre tags around var_dump, makes things easier to read in the browser
    // also note print instead of echo, I lke to do this for debugging, as it makes 
    // it easier to determine what's is debug output for those long running debugging sessions
    print '<pre>';
    var_dump($xmlraid);
    print '</pre>';
     echo "<br><br>";

    // quick and dirty solution for viewing the XML
    /*print '<textarea cols="400" rows="2000">';
    print $xmlraid->asXML();
    print '</textarea>';*/

    $achievement = $xmlraid->xpath("/achievements/category/achievement[@id='4602']");

    print '<pre>';
    var_dump($achievement);
    print '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, check [the doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php). simplexml_load_file() returns an object representing the XML into `$xmlraid`. I suggest doing a `var_dump($xmlraid);` and to verify your xpath expression.

Answer (score 0):

The document element is `achievements`.

Your **XPATH** statement should be:

```
/achievements/category/achievement[id='4602']
```

Answer (score 0):

Damn, those people are nasty browser-sniffers. I didn't do it all in vain though, this works:

```
<?php
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => 'User-Agent: Firefox/3.5.9\r\n'
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
libxml_set_streams_context($context);

$d = simplexml_load_file('http://eu.wowarmory.com/character-achievements.xml?r=Sunstrider&cn=Secrezy&c=168');
var_dump($d->xpath("//achievement[@id='4602']"));
```

The __extremely_ sad thing is, at first I just hoped it would be at least `Accept` or at the most `Accept-Encoding` - headers. But no, the *"shouldn't mean anything significant"*-`User-Agent`-header. A fine example why browser sniffing is bad if I ever saw one.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did actually have the user agent in my original code which I have now edited into the first post. simplexml_load_file seems to work now unless I try to implement it into a while loop...